# change data received with get()

Tags: jquery

How can I manipulate html received from the server with get()?

```
var jqxhr = $.get("/ajax/get_info", function(data) {  
// here I want to change the data        
$.colorbox({html:function(){          
      return data;
  }});
});
```

When using Jquery selectors it ignores the html data received, unless I append it to the DOM first.
I want to change the data before passing it to Colorbox. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, just... change the data before you pass it to colorbox:

```
$.get("/ajax/get_info", function(data) {  
  data = transform(data);  
  $.colorbox({html:function(){          
      return data;
  }});
});
```

If you want to perform DOM manipulations on an arbitrary HTML string:

```
var data = /* whatever */,
    $data = $(data),
    $divs = $data.find('div');
    // etc
```

Answer (score 1):

do whatever you want to do with data. This removes all a tags

```
data.find('a').remove();
```

Comment: No, data is a string. It has no .find() method.